# Declaring an app label error for django oauth2_provider package

Tags: python, django

I am trying to upgrade my apps django version from 1.8 to 3.2.

my root URL config is defined as:

`ROOT_URLCONF = 'clickwork.urls'`
in settings.py

inside the urls file, I have this imports:

```
from django.conf import settings
import oauth2_provider.views as oauth2_views


from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()
```

the ouath2provider import statement is throwing app_label error:

`RuntimeError: Model class django.contrib.contenttypes.models.ContentType doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.`

Here is what I have tried to resolve the issue:

1. Upgrading the oauthprovider package to the latest version 1.5, it supports Django 2.2+ as per their docs.

https://github.com/jazzband/django-oauth-toolkit

2. Adding apps.py file in the root directory and adding the path to the project config in INSTALLED_APPS in settings, this is mentioned in the Django 3.2 release notes:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/applications/#configuring-applications-ref

3. I went through the `django.contrib.contenttypes.models.ContentType` class code and added an app label, it was not there before:

```
class ContentType(models.Model):
    app_label = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    model = models.CharField(_('python model class name'), max_length=100)
    objects = ContentTypeManager()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('content type')
        verbose_name_plural = _('content types')
        db_table = 'django_content_type'
        unique_together = [['app_label', 'model']]
```

Doing step3 solves the problem but obviously changing the code in the package is dumb.

Can anyone guide me on what I am doing wrong and where and how app_label needs to be defined with the Django update, currently in Django 1.8 it is not defined anywhere.

Installed apps:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'oauth2_provider',
    'corsheaders'
    'app.apps.MyAppConfig',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'dal',
    'dal_select2',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework_swagger',
    'main',
    'user_management',
    'simplewiki',
    'reversion',
    'django_jenkins',
    'django_spaghetti',
    'django_extensions',
    'debug_toolbar',
    'django_celery_monitor',
    'query_store'
)
```

Comment: is there any apps.py file in your contenttypes folder?

Comment: yes it is there

Comment: Please share INSTALLED_APPS portion of settings.py

Comment: added now, check above